# Refining SQL Query -

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am working on a store procedure to display a list of courses based 2 criteria:

1. An administrator that does not need a courseid
2. A student that does need a courseId

I've gotten the store procedure to work; however, I would like to refine it and
make it more readable. I added a case statement, but I am getting an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted

I'd appreciate some feedback.

```
DECLARE @ROLEID INT = 1;
select *
from Courses
where courseID in (
  case when @ROLEID = 1 then (select coursedID From Department d where d.DepartmentName = 'Accounting') --a ROLEID 1 IS AN ADMINISTRATOR, so there will be several course ids returned
  else (select coursedID From Department d where d.DepartmentName = 'Accounting' and d.CourseId = 'A101') 
)

iF @ROLEID = 1)
BEGIN
    -- APPROPRIATE QUERY HERE
END ELSE 
BEGIN 
    -- APPROPRIATE QUERY HERE
END
```

Comment: Food for thought: how can the specific intersection of a row and column in a data set result in more than one value?  Another way of thinking about it is provide some same data and what you would expect to see in this case in tabular form.  You'll quickly find you have trouble doing it without embedding a table in a table. which is why the compiler is unhappy.

Comment: `case` only works for scalar values, not entire result sets. So when you do `case when @ROLEID = 1 then (...<select query>...)` it's fundamentally mismatched because `case` expects a single value, but what's being returned is a full set of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`case` only works for scalar values, not entire result sets. So when you do `case when @ROLEID = 1 then (...<select query>...)` it's fundamentally mismatched because case expects a single value, but what's being returned is a full set of data.

You could put your case statement in your inner query

```
select *
from Courses
where CourseId in (select CourseId
                   from Department
                   where DepartmentName = 'Accounting'
                       and CourseId = case when @RoleId = 1 then CourseId else 'A101' end)
```

or do it like this

```
select *
from Courses
where CourseId in (select CourseId
                   from Department
                   where DepartmentName = 'Accounting'
                       and @RoleId = 1 or CourseId = 'A101')
```

however both are subject to getting bad query plans because one query would be using @RoleId and the other would be using a column value. For performance, splitting them into separate statements is probably better in the long run

```
if @RoleId = 1
    select *
    from courses
    where DepartmentName = 'Accounting'
else
    select *
    from courses
    where CourseId = 'A101'
        and DepartmentName = 'Accounting'
```